# How to delete the App in Android

Tags: android

I downloaded the app from the eclipse to my device and like to delete the app at the device.
I tried from setting>Application Manager. But I can't find the app there. How can I delete the app?
Thanks

Comment: A quick way depending on your device/app launcher may be to press and hold the icon in the launcher, and just drag it to the appearing "delete" button. Works "standard" on HTC and both third party launchers I have on my device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it via adb using:

```
adb uninstall PACKAGE_WRITTEN_IN_MANIFEST
```

However, going to `Settings -> Application Manager -> Downloaded Apps` should list your app and allow you to delete it.

Comment: I can't find in the downloaded or all. But can see on the screen.

Comment: @Bryanyan You may not have set the name properly. Try looking in the downloaded section for your package name instead

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by following steps on Android Device

setting->Manage applications->pressLong on the application (which you want to uninstall)

Then,finally click on the UNinstall button.
YOU are Done!